# Динамический вывод из MySQL

Tags: mysql

Есть база данных с таблицами статистики, 4 идентичных таблицы с разными названиями и иерархией - //категория - подкатегория - проект - таблица с данными//, как сделать выбор данных по динамическому form select для вывода данных из конкретной таблицы по выбору категории, подкатегории и проекта?

Comment: Если коротко - берете значение категрии подкатегории и проекта - подставляете их в функцию которая сгенерирует вам вам запрос - и делаете запрос) А пока не укажете больше деталей, на каком языке вы это делаете, больше мало что сказать можно.

Answer (score 0):

Если таблицы полностью идентичны, то я рекомендую слить все данные из них в одну общую таблицу, добавить в нее индексированное поле `TYPE` и делать выборки по этому полю

Comment: Таблицы с постоянно обновляемой информацией.

Comment: @Андрей И что? Как это мешает объединить их?

Comment: Запросы, четыре разных проекта, инфо выводится в highcharts, пытаюсь написать запрос для вывода  <select name="category" id="category" class="form-control">
  <option value="">Select Category</option>

Comment: @Андрей Еще раз, повторяю медленно. Создайте **общую** таблицу, слейте в нее все данные и **удалите** Ваши идентичные таблицы. После этого все запросы на выборку и изменение данных производите с новой таблицей

Comment: Код запроса подскажите база CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Table` (
  `i` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `day` char(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dt` char(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tm` char(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `refer` text,
  `ip` char(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `proxy` char(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `host` char(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lang` char(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user` text,
  `req` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`i`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=20 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;

Comment: @Андрей Какого запроса?

Comment: SELECT все даты 'dt' и 'I' индификатор